# How to convert what is printed in the RStudio console into a document?

Tags: r, printing, rstudio

So, as the question says, I was wondering if it was possible with R, to print in a document the result of your code. In other words, the result of sourcing my script that gets printed into the console of RStudio, I'd like to have it in a document. Is this possible? Any idea as how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Check out [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)! You are about to be amazed :) Alternatively, simply click on `File` --> `New File` --> `R Markdown` in Rstudio, create the default document and then click on `Knit to HTML`. This will get you started

Comment: @tifu Okay, I'm checking it and that is a whole new world for me, woah. Thanks!

Comment: @tifu lol. That gave me a chuckle.

Comment: @tifu just to let you know that this really worked for me and I used R Markdown _a lot_ after that. So I'm genuinely thankful.

Comment: @MarcBF I'm glad my comment was useful for you...cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely **RMarkdown** was the solution to me. It is wonderful in order to generate documents based on your R code output, amongst other stuff.